# collapsing two factors into one?

Tags: r, factors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Joining factor levels of two columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855425/joining-factor-levels-of-two-columns-in-r)

I'm fairly new to R, and I'm trying to make my recoding script somewhat more effective and "correct". I've tried searching the forums but that got me nowhere - perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology and missed it, so please bear with me if the question has already been put up.

I have two factor-variables that I wish to collapse into one factor variable. They stem from the same survey and both measure educational level. The reason I have two variables in the first place is because of an unfortunate survey-construction, but thats beside the point. The main point to be made is that they are mutually exclusive (you can only be in one).

**My data looks like this:**

```
education       education2
9th grade       <NA>
9th grade       <NA>
<NA>            9th grade
<NA>            10th grade
10th grade      <NA>
11th grade      <NA>
<NA>            9th grade
<NA>            11th grade
<NA>            <NA>
```

**and my script looks like this:**

```
highest.edu     <- vector(length=length(df$education))
a.grade       <- which(df$education=="9th grade")
a.grade2      <- which(df$education2=="9th grade")
b.grade      <- which(df$education=="10th grade")
b.grade2     <- which(df$education2=="10th grade")
c.grade      <- which(df$education=="11th grade")
c.grade2     <- which(df$education=="11th grade")

highest.edu[a.grade]      <- as.character(df$education)[a.grade]
highest.edu[a.grade2]     <- as.character(df$education2)[a.grade2]
highest.edu[b.grade]     <- as.character(df$education)[b.grade]
highest.edu[b.grade2]    <- as.character(df$education2)[b.grade2]
highest.edu[c.grade]     <- as.character(df$education)[c.grade]
highest.edu[c.grade2]    <- as.character(df$education2)[c.grade2]

highest.edu  <- factor(highest.edu)
highest.edu[highest.edu =="FALSE"] =NA
highest.edu  <- factor(highest.edu)
```

Off course this is not bad but when you have two factor-variables with 15 levels a couple of times or more you start looking for quicker alternatives.

**I've tried something like this but without any luck:**

```
a.grade   <- which(df$education=="9th grade" | df$education2=="9th grade")
b.grade  <- which(df$education=="10th grade" | df$education=="10th grade")
c.grade  <- which(df$education=="11th grade" | df$education2=="11th grade")

highest.edu[a.grade]      <- as.character(df$education)  
[a.grade]|as.character(df$education2)[a.grade]
highest.edu[b.grade]      <- as.character(df$education)          
[b.grade]|as.character(df$education2)[b.grade]
```

**giving me this:**
Error in as.character(df$education)[9th grade] | as.character(df$education2)[9th grade]: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Is there a way to overcome this?

Thanks for any suggestions in advance

### edit:

**the result I'm aiming at is this:**

```
highest.education
9th grade
9th grade
9th grade
10th grade
10th grade
11th grade
9th grade
11th grade
<NA>
```

the post: 'Joining factor levels of two columns in R' seems to be going for another result

again, thank you

Comment: Can't you just use `education[is.na(education)] <- education2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once they're character strings it's easy

```
# make them character types
ed <- levels(df$education)[df$education]
ed2 <- levels(df$education2)[df$education2]
# make one new factor that integrates them
ed[is.na(ed)] <- ed2[is.na(ed)]
# make it a factor again
ed <- factor(ed)
```

You could accelerate the process by reading them in as characters in the first place, especially if you already set column types in `read.table`.

Comment: Thank you, this made it so much easier!

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure that all factor levels are present in the result:

```
levels(education) <- c(levels(education), levels(education2))
education[is.na(education)] <- education2[is.na(education)]
```

Comment: lovely solution... I just like to propagate how to make strings out of factors everywhere because I often forget it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to make sure the levels are both the "union" or "intersection" of the unique levels and in the same order, then you can join them using `c`. Search on: [r] factor union levels.